# AWS lambda read to outputs from CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I would like to read an output parameter from a CF stack dynamically in a Lambda@Edge (javascript).

Can this be achieved using the amplify library or some other way? Any examples of how to do this?

I believe I need to give the script the DescribeStack permission to do this.

Comment: Could I ask you to back up one step and explain what you are planning to do with a CloudFormation output parameter, accessed from a Lambda@Edge function, and why that seems like the right solution?  Your use case may be perfectly sensible, but I'd like to help ensure you are solving the underlying problem optimally. While possible, this sounds a little sub-optimal -- I don't know that the performance will necessarily be acceptable (requests will need to be sent back to the CloudFormation regional API from whichever edge is handling the request), and you may encounter CFN API rate limiting.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Probably getting the id of a cognito user pool for authentication purposes.

Comment: Building on previous comments can you just add an environmental variable on the function from export?

Comment: @TimBassett that would be nice, but Lambda@Edge does not permit environment variables.